# HOW TO Include resource class with .resx in the same tree?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Hi the problem that i have i don't know how to solve it.

I download a project from TFS and there is a resource class splitted form the resource designer class like the image shows.

How can i make it tree as the others withut delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires you to edit the `.csproj` file manually.

Right click on the project and select "Unload Project".
Right click on the project and select "Edit ProjectName.csproj" 
Find the Compile `ItemGroup` with your two resource names in it

```
<Compile Include="LayoutResources.en.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>LayoutResources.en.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

You need to make the "main" menu item dependent on the sub-item (seems backwards, but that is how it works). You can now save and close the `.csproj` file, right click it again and reload.